# setState not working properly when using value={} in input field

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React JS.
I am setting the state, however, there is a problem, in the value={} part of the input field.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';



class SomeClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            passCode: {
                email: "Email",
                password: "Password"
            },
            errorMessage: ''
        };
    }



    handleChange = (event) =>{
        console.log(`input detected`);
        let request = Object.assign({},this.state.passCode);
        request.email = event.target.value;
        request.password = event.target.value;
        this.setState({passCode: request});
     }


    
    
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.passCode.email} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter Email Address" />
  
                    <label>Password</label>   
                    <input type="password" value={this.state.passCode.password} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter One Time Password" />

                <Button type="submit">
                    Sign In</Button>
            </form>
        );
    }
    
}


export default SomeClass;
```

**My Question:**

I have is for the value attribute of the input fields, I think setState is not working properly:

In the passCode object of the state.
When I type the email, both fields get set to what I typed in the email field.
When I type the password, both fields get set to what I typed in the password field.

What's the reason for such problem?

Comment: Both have the same handler, and that handler sets both values to the same: `request.email = event.target.value; request.password = event.target.value`. So I don't know why this behaviour is a surprise to you. You need to either have separate handlers which only set the appropriate field, or keep one handler but have it read the id/name of the input (once you provide these) to decide which field of the state to update.

Comment: Instead of using object.assign why not just set the object directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your funtion `handleChange` is wrong. You should update like this with using `name`:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log(`input detected`);
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({ passCode: { ...this.state.passCode, [name]: value } });
};
```

And set `name` to `input`:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.passCode.email} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email" />
<input type="password" value={this.state.passCode.password} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter One Time Password" name="password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is working properly; your `handleChange` isn't. You're setting **both** `email` **and** `password` to the value of the input regardless of which input the change occurred on. Instead, you want to update just the relevant property. To do that, I'd add `name` attributes to the `input` elements (`name="email"` and `name="password"`), then:

```
handleChange = ({currentTarget: {name, value}}) =>{
    console.log(`input detected`);
    this.setState(({passCode}) => {
        return {passCode: {...passCode, [name]: value}};
    });
};
```

Key bits there are:

- It only updates the property the `change` related to, keeping the other one unchanged, by using the name of the input.
- It uses the callback version of `setState` (best practice since we're setting state based on existing state).

Comment: *(Oops, I left out a layer. If you don't see the `{passCode: ...}` part of `return {passCode: {...passCode, [name]: value}};` above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: Nice flex on the nested destructuring

Comment: @RameshReddy - :-) Habit from from back before React v17 when you couldn't use the event object asynchronously (because it was pooled and reused).

Answer (score 0):

The methods they gaved are good, but I still suggest that you separate the methods of changing the two, maybe it will be much better.